# ora-00906: missing left parenthesis while creating table

Tags: oracle, ddl

I am using oracle pl.sql developer. I have two schemas, and I want to create a table from one schema in another schema. I used dbms_metadata.getddl() to retrieve the create table script. However, when i run that script in another schema, i get ORA-00906L missing left parenthesis error. Code is following:

```
  CREATE TABLE "DWH"."IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1" OF "DWH"."IBS_S_DOCUMENT_T_1"
 (
   CONSTRAINT "XPK_S_DOCUMENT" PRIMARY KEY ("CODE")
  USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "DWH"."XPK_S_DOCUMENT" ON "DWH"."IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1"
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DWH_INDEX" )  ENABLE,
   CONSTRAINT "HSYS_005480" CHECK (DATE_ACTIV IS NOT NULL) ENABLE,
   CONSTRAINT "HSYS_005481" CHECK (DATE_CORRECT IS NOT NULL) ENABLE,
   CONSTRAINT "HSYS_005482" CHECK (CORRECTURE IS NOT NULL) ENABLE,
   CONSTRAINT "HSYS_005483" CHECK (Correcture IN ('A', 'C', 'D', 'T', 'U')) ENABLE
  ) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY
   PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(
    INITIAL 16384 NEXT 16384 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DWH_DATA"
 NESTED TABLE "IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1_H" STORE AS "IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1_HIS"
 (( PRIMARY KEY ("NESTED_TABLE_ID", "DATE_ACTIV") ENABLE)
 ORGANIZATION INDEX PCTTHRESHOLD 50
 NOCOMPRESS PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 16384 NEXT 16384 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DWH_INDEX" ) RETURN AS VALUE
```

IBS_S_DOCUMENT_T_1 type is the following:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "IBS_S_DOCUMENT_T_1"                                          as object (
  CODE                           VarChar2(2),
  NAME                           IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1_NVT,
  DATE_ACTIV                     DATE,
  DATE_DEACT                     DATE,
  DATE_CORRECT                   DATE,
  CORRECTURE                     VarChar2(1),
  CONDITION                      VarChar2(1),
  IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1_H                   IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1_NT
);
```

Why am i getting ora-00906 error? Can anybody help?

Comment: (Not of much importance; however, It is not "oracle pl.sql developer" but Oracle SQL Developer). As you already use that tool, click table name - on right hand side its description will open. The last tab is called "SQL" - click it. Copy that code and paste it into another schema. Any improvement?

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I am using pl/sql developer. From what you said, i found 'view sql' in columns tab, but using that sql didn't work, so I tried to use ddl of the table and it seems it worked. Thanks, again

Comment: Aha; so it is Allround Automations' PL/SQL Developer, then. I'm glad if you managed to fix the problem.

Comment: To all communities' most respectful dear members for Oracle tag : There are `ora-00900`, `ora-00904`, `ora-00907` tags but no `ora-00906` tag ... Please interest :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this part `(CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "DWH"."XPK_S_DOCUMENT" ON "DWH"."IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1"` after `USING INDEX`, and remove `)` just before the first `ENABLE` of course, then it will work :

```
  CREATE TABLE "DWH"."IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1" OF "DWH"."IBS_S_DOCUMENT_T_1"
 (
   CONSTRAINT "XPK_S_DOCUMENT" PRIMARY KEY ("CODE")
  USING INDEX --(CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "DWH"."XPK_S_DOCUMENT" ON "DWH"."IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1"
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DWH_INDEX" --)  
                         ENABLE,
   CONSTRAINT "HSYS_005480" CHECK (DATE_ACTIV IS NOT NULL) ENABLE,
   CONSTRAINT "HSYS_005481" CHECK (DATE_CORRECT IS NOT NULL) ENABLE,
   CONSTRAINT "HSYS_005482" CHECK (CORRECTURE IS NOT NULL) ENABLE,
   CONSTRAINT "HSYS_005483" CHECK (Correcture IN ('A', 'C', 'D', 'T', 'U')) ENABLE
  ) OBJECT IDENTIFIER IS PRIMARY KEY
   PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(
    INITIAL 16384 NEXT 16384 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DWH_DATA"
 NESTED TABLE "IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1_H" STORE AS "IBS_S_DOCUMENT_1_HIS"
 (( PRIMARY KEY ("NESTED_TABLE_ID", "DATE_ACTIV") ENABLE)
 ORGANIZATION INDEX PCTTHRESHOLD 50
 NOCOMPRESS PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 16384 NEXT 16384 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DWH_INDEX" ) RETURN AS VALUE
```

No need to express `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` for `PRIMARY KEY` which will already be created with the given name `XPK_S_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  That was the problem